# Get the size of a Node in a given layout in javafx 2.0?

Tags: java, javafx-2

In the skin of a custom control I would like to draw a triangle the size of the control, and have the triangle grow as the frame is resized. I have the following code but the bounds only increase in size as I resize the frame. How to I get it to resize correctly?

```
private void update()
{
    Bounds bounds = node.getBoundsInParent();
    Path path = new Path();
    path.getElements().add(
            new MoveTo(
            bounds.getWidth() / 2 + bounds.getMinX(), 
            bounds.getMinY()));
    path.getElements().add(
            new LineTo(bounds.getMaxX(), bounds.getMaxY()));
    path.getElements().add(
            new LineTo(bounds.getMinX(), bounds.getMaxY()));
   path.setFill(Color.RED);
   node.getChildren().setAll(path);                
}
```

Edit: Using swing I would do the following. But I can't get it to work in JavaFX.

```
public class Arrow extends JPanel
{

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
    super.paintComponent(graphics);
    Dimension size = getSize();

    Point top = new Point(size.width/2,0);
    Point bottomRight = new Point(size.width, size.height);
    Point bottomLeft = new Point(0, size.height);

    GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
    path.moveTo(top.x, top.y);
    path.lineTo(bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y);
    path.lineTo(bottomLeft.x, bottomLeft.y);
    path.lineTo(top.x, top.y);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)graphics.create();
    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2d.fill(path);
    g2d.dispose();
}
}
```

Comment: I can't get what's wrong with "bounds only increase in size as I resize the frame"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the skin of a custom control I would like to draw a triangle the size of the control, and have the triangle grow as the frame is resized.

The ScrollBar thumb implementation in the default Caspian style for JavaFX does exactly this.  It does it via a -fx-shape css attribute:

```
.scroll-bar:vertical .increment-arrow {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-mark-highlight-color, -fx-mark-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 1 0 -1 0, 0;
    -fx-padding: 0.333333em 0.5em 0.0em 0.0em; /* 4 6 0 0 */
    -fx-shape: "M -3 0 L 0 4 L 3 0 z";
}
```

[Documentation of -fx-shape](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) is:

> An SVG path string. By specifying a shape here the region takes on that shape instead of a rectangle or rounded rectangle. The syntax of this path string.

---

Now to your apparently unrelated question title:

> Get the size of a Node in a given layout in javafx 2.0?

So what size do you really want?

The Node's visual bounds is it's [bounds in parent](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getBoundsInParent%28%29).
The Node's [layout bounds](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getLayoutBounds%28%29) is:

> The rectangular bounds that should be used for layout calculations for this node. layoutBounds may differ from the visual bounds of the node and is computed differently depending on the node type.

If you don't use the -fx-shape css stuff I mentioned earlier (for what you are doing), you probably want to use layout bounds as you will be laying out your Triangle within the parent Region of the Control and your Triangle would automatically inherit any transforms applied to the parent Region.

Layout for a Node is often not completely calculated until it has been added to an active scene and a css pass been executed on the Node.  So you can add a listener to the appropriate property (e.g. boundsInLocal) and update your triangle rendering whenever the listener gets fired.  This can be done without creating a custom control and skin.

If you do go the custom control and skin route, then you can override your control's [layoutChildren](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#layoutChildren%28%29) method and do your layout work in there - but this is a fairly sophisticated, advanced use case, that is often unnecessary unless you are trying to create performance critical, reusable controls.